# Determine percentage from count() without cast issues

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, count, cast

I'm trying to run the following query to provide the % of rows in my `patients` table that have a value the `refinst` column. I keep getting a result of 0.

```
select (count (refinst) / (select count(*) from patients) * 100) as "Formula" 
from patients;
```

The table has 15556 rows, and `select count(refinst) from patients` tells me that 1446 of those have a value in the `refinst` column. The response I'd like to get from the query would be 30.62 (`1446/15556*100=30.62XXXXX`, rounded to two decimals).

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the data type of the count results (integers I'm assuming). If I divide an integer by an integer and the result is less than 0 it is truncated to 0 correct? If that's the case, can someone show me how to cast the results of the counts as a number with 2 decimal places so that the result will be rounded to 2 decimal places as well?

I'm sure there's a better way to write this code than multiple count statements. I am looking for a more processor-efficient way to write this query in particular.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285834/how-to-work-out-percent-in-postgresql-using-count) can helps you.

Answer (score 28):

```
SELECT (count(refinst) * 100)::numeric / NULLIF(count(*), 0) AS refinst_pct
    -- count(refinst) * 100.0 / NULLIF(count(*), 0) AS refinst_pct  -- simpler
FROM   patients;
```

- Do **not** use a subselect. Both aggregates can be derived from the same query. Cheaper.
- Also, this is **not** a case for window functions, since you want to compute a single result, and not one result per row.
- Cast to any [numeric type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html) that supports fractional digits, like [@a_horse already explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69111/3684).
  Since you want to [**`round()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html) to two fractional digits I suggest **`numeric`** (which is the same as `decimal` in Postgres).
  It's enough to cast *one* value involved in a calculation, preferably the first. Postgres automatically settles for the type that does not lose information.
  Or, simpler yet: since we multiply anyway, use a [numeric constant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.9.2) that's coerced to `numeric` automatically because of the decimal point (`100.0`).
- It's generally a good idea to **multiply *before* you divide**. This typically minimizes rounding errors and is cheaper.
  In this case, the first multiplication (`count(refinst) * 100`) can be computed with cheap and exact `integer` arithmetic. Only *then* we cast to `numeric` and divide by the next `integer` (which we do *not* cast additionally).
- `NULLIF(count(*), 0)` prevents division by zero (raising an exception). We get NULL as (unknown) percentage if there are no rows at all.

Rounded to two fractional digits:

```
SELECT round((count(refinst) * 100)::numeric / NULLIF(count(*), 0), 2) AS refinst_pct
FROM   patients;
```

Comment: Of course you are right, the window function is not needed. But then it doesn't really make a difference (apart from readability).

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast each number involved in the division to a type that supports decimals:

```
select (count(refinst)::decimal / (select count(*) from patients)::decimal) * 100  as "Formula" 
from patients;
```

You might also want to try a window function instead of the scalar sub-query. It might be faster:

```
select (count(refinst)::decimal / (count(*) over ())::decimal) * 100 as "Formula" 
from patients;
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this thread is a couple of years old but:
try multiplying by 100.0 rather than by 100 
That should automatically cast the result as a float rather than an integer.

Comment: Good idea. The result is `numeric`, though. Even better for the task.